# Plesk 12.0.30 crash after update

Tags: plesk

I just want update my Plesk to 12.0.30, but after the update, I cannot access my panel.

The server is on CentOS.

```
[root@******* ~]# /etc/init.d/psa restart
PSA is down, performing full restart.
Starting psa... Starting sw-engine-fpm: chmod: cannot access `/dev/shm': No such file or directory
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Unable to init lock manager shared memory file: Unable to create new lock manager shared memory storage. Please, try to restart sw-engine service as root.
/bin/bash: line 1:  1209 Aborted                 /usr/sbin/sw-engine-fpm --fpm-config /etc/sw-engine/sw-engine-fpm.conf -c /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini
                                                           [FAILED]
                                                                      failed
Starting xinetd service...                                            done
Starting sw-cp-server service...                                      done
Starting mysqld service...                                            done
Starting named service...                                             done
Starting postgresql service...                                        not installed
Starting spamassassin service...                                      not installed
Plesk: Starting Mail Server... already started
Starting psa... Starting sw-engine-fpm: chmod: cannot access `/dev/shm': No such file or directory
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Unable to init lock manager shared memory file: Unable to create new lock manager shared memory storage. Please, try to restart sw-engine service as root.
/bin/bash: line 1:  1316 Aborted                 /usr/sbin/sw-engine-fpm --fpm-config /etc/sw-engine/sw-engine-fpm.conf -c /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini
                                                           [FAILED]
                                                                      failed
Starting drwebd service...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# mkdir /dev/shm 
# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /dev/shm 
# /etc/init.d/psa start
```

Solution on vserver Server4you  ubuntu 12

Answer (score 0):

Solution (CentOS):

```
 # mkdir /dev/shm
 # mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /dev/shm
 # /etc/init.d/psa start
```